Graph isomorphism checking/detection for directed acyclic graphs
The graph isomorphism problem is hard for an arbitrary graph, and certain classes of graphs have been proven to be "GI-complete", which as I understand means they can be reformulated in terms of a polynomial number of dual problems which themselves take polynomial time to solve.
From wikipedia:

In computational complexity theory, a polynomial-time reduction is a
method for solving one problem using another. One shows that if a
hypothetical subroutine solving the second problem exists, then the
first problem can be solved by transforming or reducing it to inputs
for the second problem and calling the subroutine one or more times.
If both the time required to transform the first problem to the
second, and the number of times the subroutine is called is
polynomial, then the first problem is polynomial-time reducible to the
second.


I am wondering about direct acyclic graphs (a.k.a. feed-forward neural networks) specifically not because I have a research interest in them but because I happen to be confronted with them while studying the NEAT algorithm (video: video), which is a genetic/evolutionary algorithm that searches the space of different neural network architectures to find the "fittest" one for a particular task. The NEAT algorithm owes its success to the efficient way in which this exploration takes place: by uniquely labelling each edge (essentially keeping a bijective map in storage mapping a number, the "innovation number", to each possible edge) the algorithm ensures we don't create the "same" graph a second time. There is also this other thing called speciation, which is a measure of how different two graphs are based on the number of extra edges one graph has compared to another, the number of edges that appear in exactly one and not two of the graphs, and the average edge weight difference taken over all shared edges in the two graphs.
But it seems that the NEAT algorithm does not address the possibility of graphs being isomorphic. Speciation looks at the "genomes" of the two graphs.
BTW computer scientists use biology vocabulary, but:

gene:



edge gene: edge encoding (of the form [innovation number, (v1, v2), enabled_bool, edge_weight])




node gene: similar but node info


genome: set of genes. Encodes a network. Any network produced by neat should have a unique genome

phenotype: the actual graph (or network) produced by the genome


Just wanted to get that out of the way.
So, genomes are the thing that's used to manipulate candidate networks, and the measure of how different two graphs are is a function of their genomes. But my concern is that you could have two graphs that look very similar but with completely different genomes, or two genomes that are close with respect to the speciation formula, but whose phenotypes that are completely different.
The type II error here would be to have very similar graphs (topologically speaking) but with a large speciation difference measure, leading to wasted compute resources.

This may seem trivial, and I will look like an idiot if someone posts a small 3 node counter example in a comment, but if one wants to check that two DAGs (directed acyclic graphs) are not isomorphic isn't it enough to do the following:
(Let $d^{(v)}_{in}$ and $d^{(v)}_{out}$ be the in-degree and out-degree of a given node $v$.)
For each graph compute the set $\{(d^{(v)}_{in},d^{(v)}_{out})\ \ |\ \  v\in V\}$. If the two sets are the same then the graphs are isomorphic, and if they are not the same, the graphs are not isomorphic.
I tried some examples by hand and it really seems like this degree-pairs set criterion is plausible.

Here's a simple counterexample for the claim that looking at in/out degrees is enough:


The sets of in/out degrees are the same. But these are not isomorphic because the first DAG has two paths of length $5$, while the second one has only one.
I know that for undirected graphs, degree solves isomorphism problem for graphs with nodes up to 5. I don't know about DAG case though, in the above example we can actually remove node $5$ and it will still work. So for DAG, if degree solves isomorphism problem for DAGs with nodes up to $n$, then $n\leq 4$ necessarily. But what is the actual $n$? I don't know.
However the general isomorphism problem for DAGs (even rooted) is equivalent to the isomorphism problem for undirected graphs. And therefore finding a polynomial time solution would be rather spectacular.
I don't know much about NEAT algorithm. Maybe someone else can elaborate on that. But it sounds highly unlikely that it produces non-isomorphic graphs in each step. Maybe it isn't actually relevant.
As requested in comments: here's another example of non-isomorphic DAGs, this time with "per level" equal in/out degrees:

The only difference between those graphs is that I moved arrow for node $6$ to point to $9$ instead of $10$. Those are non-isomorphic, because if I remove root node, then on the left I end up with disconnected (in the unordered sense) graph, while on the right it remains connected. But in/out degrees are not only equal globally, but also equal if grouped vertically. Which is what you refer to in comments.

Thanks for the answer, and clever counter example! I want to politely challenge you (and whoever reads this) to come up with a counterexample for this modified criterion:
It's an ordered variant of the original. We create an ordered list of in/out degree pairs sets starting at the nodes with in-degree zero, then their direct non-visited out-neighbours, etc. For your counter-example the new criterion gives
Graph 1: [{(0,1),(0,1)},{(2,1)},{(1,1)},{(1,1)},{(1,0)}]
Graph 2: [{(0,1),(0,1)},{(1,1),(2,1)},{(1,1)},{(1,0)}]

@JohnCataldo the problem with your variant is that this procedure is not well defined, since a single dag may have multiple different such orderings, depending on which root you start, and choice of children. And there is no way to distinguish them.

It's a list of sets, so the first set considers all root nodes and looks at their in/out degrees as a set. So it doesn't matter what order you look at the nodes. I hope I am not misunderstanding something. We consider all roots as the first set, and all of those roots' children as the second set, then those children's children etc.

Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the construction. So you are asking about per level comparison. This is again polynomial so I'm pretty sure there is a counterexample. But I don't have one yet, I will get back to you.

I really think the procedure is well-defined. After adding edge (1,3) in both graphs we get G1: [{(0,1),(0,1)}, {(2,1),(2,1)}, {(1,1)}, {(1,1)}] this corresponds to nodes [{1,0},{2,3},{4},{5}]
G2: [{(0,2),(0,1)}, {(1,1),(3,1)}, {(1,1)}, {1,0}], or in terms of nodes [{1,0}, {2,3}, {4},{5}]

@JohnCataldo I've updated the answer with a counterexample.
